# How can I get gcalcli to work on Python 36?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Old-time user, first-time asker here,

I am very new to Python, and I started by downloading Anaconda with Pyhon 3.6.  I tried to get gcalcli to work, but it's having big Python version conflicts.  It looks like gcalcli was made for Python 2, but then my "default" Python is 3.  Many of the modules gcacli needs have also been installed for Python 3.  I think that even the print command has changed between the two versions.

I believe I have all the necessary modules installed: Google API Client, dateutil, gflag, but their versions might be part of the problem.

I can run gcalcli from Python 2 (by changing the first line in the gcalcli file) but it will crash when a Python 3 module is needed and the syntax is strange.  I also tried running gcacli from Python 3, but the same happens when it runs into syntax that only works for Python 2.

I tried copying the content in the Python36/Lib folders to Python27/Lib, and run gcalcli from Python 2.  That helped the program run a bit further, until it ran into another incompatible bit of syntax.  In other words, I'm kinda trapped in version hell.

Has anyone found a solution for this kind of version and script/module compatibility problem?

Thank you, very much.